# why the Form Object is still live when variable goes out of scope?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, scope, local-variables

Here is question :

```
Private void   buttonFrmshow_Click(..)
{ 
  frmEmployee f = new frmEmployee() //frmEmployee is derived from System.Windows.Form;
  f.Show();
}
```

Now that f is local variable having scope limited to buttonclick Method, 
1. Why would the Employee form be active all the time though the varible scope is finished ?
2. Will it be automatically GCed ?
3. The variable f in above code shows it's null, still the employee form is active ? What is happening behind the scenes ?

Has it something to do with Threading ?

Comment: Shall I be treating Form object as unmanaged resource ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When new forms are created, they are added to the [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx) collection, which will keep them in scope once the local variable goes out of scope.

Closing the form will remove it from that collection and allow it to be collected.

Comment: Is Application.OpenForms the first check point of GC before GCing the forms ?

Comment: It's not necessarily the first checkpoint. The GC is a complex beast. If an object can no longer be referenced by another object, it is eligible for collection. So, if it's that collection, it wont' be GCd. If it is, then it will be at some point. There's no 'first check' per se.

Answer (score 0):

Lets make one thing straight.

As long as a reference type object (Form here) is referenced GC will never touch it. Once the reference is removed then only GC can be allowed to reclaim the resources.

After instantiating a form it is referenced contineously by calling various paint methods even when it is idle. unless it is explicitly closed by the user, or OS shell it will keep occupying the resources under Application's main thread.